# Angular reactive form : hasError function returns true but error is not displayed

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I've a weird problem with angular reactive form specially with "hasError" function. I check if my input contains a mac address. The function hasError sends me true but the error is not displayed.

I get my data from an API. The data has been sent by postman software not by my form so it's not a normal way. BUT the problem is here and I would like to understand it.

Here my code :

component.ts

```
             // form init
const macAddressPattern =  "^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$";
const ipPattern =  "^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$";

            this.deviceForm = fb.group({
                'name': fb.control('', [Validators.required]),
                'model': fb.control('', [Validators.required]),
                'brand': fb.control('', [Validators.required]),
                'mac_address': fb.control('', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(macAddressPattern)])),
                'ip': fb.control('', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(ipPattern)])),
            });
```

component.html

```
<mat-form-field class="form-input">
                                    <input matInput formControlName="mac_address" required
                                    placeholder="mac address">
                                    <mat-error *ngIf="deviceForm.controls['mac_address'].hasError('pattern')">
                                            bad mac address // not displayed
                                    </mat-error>
                                    <!--<mat-error *ngIf="deviceForm.controls['mac_address'].hasError('required')">
                                        The field is required
                                    </mat-error>-->


                                </mat-form-field>

                                <pre> has error : {{deviceForm.controls.mac_address.hasError('pattern')}} </pre> // has error : true
```

Any idea ? Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

1. You can simplify your syntax to that :

   ```
   'mac_address': '', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(macAddressPattern)],
   ```
2. You should use another syntax for the error

   ```
   *ngIf="deviceForm.get('mac_address').hasError('pattern')"
   ```

This syntax works for me. If it doesn't, make a sandbox so that we can see the issue and play with it.

Comment: 1. That's what I had before to change for "compose".
2. I've tested it but same result : the hasError function sends me true but the error isn't displayed. Is it possible to force the deviceForm to display error when I'm using patchValue ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best way but it works : I simulate the user touched each field of my form to display error.

```
    initFormValues() {
        this.deviceForm.patchValue(myObj);

        // edit mode 
        if (this.deviceForm.invalid && this.updateForm) {
            this.markFormGroupTouched(this.deviceForm);
        }
    }


    public markFormGroupTouched(formGroup: FormGroup) {
        Object.values(formGroup.controls).forEach(control => {
          control.markAsTouched();
        });
    }
```

or for es2016

```
    public markFormGroupTouched(formGroup: FormGroup) {
        for(let i in formGroup.controls) {
            formGroup.controls[i].markAsTouched();
        }
    }
```